# Spacewalk Clients Not Running Yum Updates

Tags: yum, update, package-management, packages, spacewalk

The clients registered with my spacewalk server report needing updates but when I schedule a event to update the packages on the clients they never perform the update. The little clock icon appears on the clients and there is a pending event but nothing happens.

I can log onto to each client and run "**yum history**" but there is nothing new reported to show that update actions are being performed. I am running **spacewalk 2.8**. I've tried cancelling and rescheduling a new update event, ran the command on each client to have it check in with the spacewalk server but no luck.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.